logits and labels do not have same shape
this is my code for translation machine(english to spainsh)
# import what i need
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/spa-eng.zip'

path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('spa-eng.zip', origin=url, cache_dir='dataset', extract=True)
path = '/tmp\\.keras\\datasets\\spa-eng.zip'
from pathlib import Path
text = (Path(path).with_name('spa-eng') / 'spa.txt').read_text(encoding='utf-8')


# this part is for customization
text = text.replace('¿', '').replace('¡', '')
pairs = [line.split('\t') for line in text.splitlines()]
np.random.shuffle(pairs)
sentences_en, sentences_es = zip(*pairs)


# use text vectorization and biuld my model
vocab_size = 10000
max_length = 50
text_vec_layer_en = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(vocab_size,                 output_sequence_length=max_length)
text_vec_layer_es = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(vocab_size,     output_sequence_length=max_length)

text_vec_layer_en.adapt(sentences_en)
text_vec_layer_es.adapt([f"startofseq {s} endofseq" for s in sentences_es])

X_train = tf.constant(sentences_en[:100_000])
X_valid = tf.constant(sentences_en[100_000:])
X_tarin_dec = tf.constant([f"startofseq {s}" for s in sentences_es[:100_000]])
X_valid_dec = tf.constant([f"startofseq {s}" for s in sentences_es[100_000:]])
Y_train = text_vec_layer_es([f"{s} endofseq" for s in sentences_es[:100_000]])
Y_valid = text_vec_layer_es([f"{s} endofseq" for s in sentences_es[100_000:]])

encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)

embed_size = 128
encoder_input_ids = text_vec_layer_en(encoder_inputs)
decoder_input_ids = text_vec_layer_es(decoder_inputs)

encoder_embeding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, mask_zero=True)
decoder_embeding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, mask_zero=True)

encoder_embeddings = encoder_embeding_layer(encoder_input_ids)
decoder_embeddings = encoder_embeding_layer(decoder_input_ids)

encoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, *encoder_state = encoder(encoder_embeddings)

encoder1 = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_state=True))
encoder_outputs1, *encoder_state1 = encoder(encoder_embeddings)
encoder_state1 = [tf.concat(encoder_state[::2], axis=-1),    
             tf.concat(encoder_state[1::2], axis=-1)]
print(encoder_state1)
print(encoder_state)
decoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder(decoder_embeddings, initial_state=encoder_state1)

output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')
Y_proba = output_layer(decoder_outputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs=[Y_proba])

# compile model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# after compile we have to fit it
model.fit((X_train, X_tarin_dec), Y_train, epochs=10,
          validation_data=((X_valid, X_valid_dec), Y_valid))`

but when i fit this model it give me this error and i don't know why
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,10000] and labels shape [1600]
[[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_252748]
and i tried to fit this model and it give me this error
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,10000] and labels shape [1600]
[[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_252748]
what is the problem?
